# Tribal dominated districts

Tags: usage

Is it correct to use **tribal dominated districts**

In the following sentence I don’t understand the grammar behind **tribal dominated districts**

The second phase of the programme — launched by Tribal Affairs Minister Arjun Munda — will digitally mentor 5,000 young women in India’s **tribal dominated districts**.

**tribal** itself is an adjective. I think it should be **tribes dominated districts**

Comment: Do you mean something different from India's officially recognised **tribal districts**?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be "picky", the issue is that the past tense ***verb*** "dominated" should perhaps be modified by an ***adverb***. Thus *a **tribally-dominated** district* (it's common in such contexts to link the adverb to a past-participle verb with a hyphen).

But this is really just a matter of established idiomatic usage in specific contexts. I don't see a big difference between a ***tribal dominated*** district and ***hot-pressed*** olive oil, for example (and *nobody* refers to ***hotly-pressed*** or ***heat-pressed*** oil).

In practice though, I think most native speakers would see the specific cited usage as being at least *slightly* "awkward", so they'd probably prefer something a bit more explicit, such as ***districts dominated by tribal allegiance*** or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be hyphenated, like "tribal-dominated".  To me, it doesn't seem that different from "male-dominated" or "female-dominated".  We never say "males-dominated" or "males dominated fields".

The grammar is much looser (or at least different) when making hyphenated compound words.  We use words like "yellow-bellied" which doesn't mean bellied in a yellow way, it means having a yellow belly.  Also, "wrong-headed", "blue-eyed", "brown-haired", etc.  "haired" isn't even a word by itself (at least not a common one).

By checking google, it seems "tribal dominated state" is far more common than "tribally dominated state" or "tribes dominated state".